# Given $\limsup \frac{a_n}{b_n} < \infty$. Prove there is a constant M such that $a_n \leq Mb_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Given sequences $\{a_n\}$ , $\{b_n\}$ of positive real numbers and $\textrm{ limsup } \frac{a_n}{b_n} < \infty$. Prove there is a constant M such that $a_n \leq Mb_n$

> > **Defn:** Let $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence. Define the sequence $c_n = \sup \{a_{k}: k \geq n\}$ for $n \geq 1$. If the sequence $c_n$ converges, then the value it converges to is the limit superior of $(a_n)$.

**Attempt:**

So given that the lim sup is finite, it means there exists a value M such that for all $n > k$, $$\frac{a_n}{b_n} < M \\ \Rightarrow \ a_n \leq Mb_n$$

**Comment:** Surely there is more to it than this and I have missed something.....

Comment: You haven't been explicit about where the $M$ comes from. Is it something like $\limsup + \epsilon$? And that only works for $n>k$. Your original problem was stated for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Still amazed that these legends of Mathematics contribute to my simple questions...........The question didn't explicitly state anything about the $M$. All I've done up to this point is prove the usual properties of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ that most analysis textbooks have you start out with.

Comment: Well, then write it out carefully please. I don't see (without a little work) where your sentence comes from, and I added my additional complaint/suggestion.

Comment: What is the definition of $\limsup$ that you are working with?

Comment: What specifically did you mean to write out carefully? My assumption on the $limsup being finite?      @JoséCarlosSantos just edited the question.

Comment: @dc3rd That definition makes no sense. Are you claiming that *each* $b_n$ is the $\limsup$ of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos isn't the $\limsup$ a sequence of values? Specifically the supremums of the sequence $a_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: **No!** The superior limit of a sequence of real numbers is a real number, $\infty$, or $-\infty$.

Comment: Ah...So I left out a line when I wrote the definition because I thought it didn't add anything, specifically that $b_n$ converges, so from what you said that means the $\limsup$ is the value that the sequence $b_n$ converges to.

Comment: If $\{a_n \}$ is bounded, then $\{ b_n \}$ is monotonically decreasing (not necessarily strictly) so either it's bounded below and its limit exists, or it's not bounded below in which case its limit is $- \infty$.  But it's not true that all (or even any) of the members of the sequence $\{ b_n \}$ must be less than the $\lim \sup$.  Let $a_n = b_n = \frac 1n$  Then $\lim \sup a_n (= \lim a_n) = 0$ even though every single element of the sequence is strictly positive.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite as simple as you make it in your proof because the sequence may approach the $\lim \sup$ from above.  The following proof works, though:

Let $M_1= \lim \sup \frac{a_n}{b_n}$.  Then $\exists N~ n \gt N \Rightarrow \frac{a_n}{b_n} \lt M_1+1.$  Let $M_2 = \max \{ \frac{a_n}{b_n} \vert ~n \leq N \}.$  Let $M = \max \{M_1+1, M_2+1 \}$.  Then $\forall n \in \Bbb N~\frac{a_n}{b_n} \lt M \text{ so } a_n \lt Mb_n.$

Comment: In your comment you mentioned that the sequence $b_n$ is monotonically decreasing. So you defining $M_2$ as you did accounts for the possibility of there being a larger value than the $\limsup$ from earlier in the sequence.

Comment: I meant $b_n$ in the definition you've given of $\lim \sup$.  It's a little confusing because you used the same letter as in your problem statement, but with two different meanings.  The point is just that the $\lim \sup$ *always* exists (if you allow $\pm \infty$ as possible values).  But yes, I'm using $M_2$ to account for the possibility that early terms of the sequence have large values.  Since there are only finitely many early terms, that's not a problem -- just take the largest.

Comment: I changed the designation of my sequence in the definition. I'm not sure if you can edit your comment, but if possible for completeness. Thank you

Comment: Too late.  There's only a limited window of time to edit comments.